# indexing and navigating in S3 metadata

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-sentry, data-lake, cloudera-director

I'm getting an important number of S3 CSV files, for each 
`fo.csv` S3 file there is a `fo.metadata.txt` file with interesting metadata describing csv columns and giving additional info.

I'm looking for the best way to navigate in the metadata of all csv file to quickly get information and found relation between different CSV columns.

Comment: do you need the metadata of the `fo.metadata.txt` file or you want to read the content ? also what you mean by _navigate in the metadata of all csv file to quickly get information and found relation between different CSV columns_ I think it'll be best if you can extend you question with some example

Comment: we have `fo.metadata.txt` and want to read it to index the content. A search on one keyword related to a `column_42` of `fo12.csv` will return: fo12.csv column_42 and all other columns/csv file that are indexed on the same keyword.